# .Net based Content Management System for marketing department

Tags: content-management-system

I need to set up a CMS for our marketing dept. Basically they need a system that they can

- sharing documents with multiple users
- editing documents with multiple users
- tracking changes
- tracking/keeping multiple versions
- storing and organizing files

The types of documents are : Illustrator, Photoshop, Pdf, MS word and Excel.

I am in the process of evaluating different CMS to use. Since we are a .Net shop so the first requirement is Windows based. I know we can use Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 or DotNetNuke.

Could anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're looking for a CMS so much as a DMS (Document Management System).  CMS are usually used for managing web-based content as opposed to documents, or if they do document management they usually do a poor job at it.

For basic management of Illustrator, Photoshop, Pdf, MS word and Excel documents I would look to something along the lines of SharePoint - it will suit your needs well for the PDF / Office documents, though I'm not sure how well it does with Illustration / Photoshop files - I'm sure it will store them but you might not have the full advantage of indexing provided by Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

[SiteCore](http://www.sitecore.net/) is a tad bit on the expensive side, but for what it does it's well worth the investment. I've had a demo of the application and was very impressed with what SiteCore offers for end users. The application is developed in .net so any asp.net developers will be able to add, adjust and modify different items for you.

You've spoke about digital assest management, well [here is Razuna](http://www.razuna.org/download), it's an open source digital assest management system that has several kinds of downloads to play with, one even being a pre-setup Virtual Image which can get you started right away. Take a look at it and see what you think.

Good luck on your search, and hope this helped some.

Comment: Sitecore does not work very well for simple document management, and is better suited to website content management.  It would be extreme overkill for what he is looking for.

Comment: Actually I suggested SiteCore because of it's ability to manage the workflow of publishing content and following any revisions of said content. For a pure document mangement system, SharePoint would be a better solution.

Comment: Does anyone have experience on DAM ( Digital Asset Management)? I guess jspru is right. What I am looking for is more of a DMS than a CMS. I learned the concept of DAM after searching on DMS. And I think a DAM is more suitable for me in this project? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider Google Docs to begin with.

Otherwise, SharePoint can handle the office documents fairly well. If it's just for the marketing team, the 'free' Windows Sharepoint Services should suffice.

You may then want to look into Adobe Version Cue to handle the Adobe based art files.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Adobe Version Cue as well.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative thought would be to consider [Version Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), so for example [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) could work for storing changes, keeping track of changes, etc.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this too. A Version Control system may solve all the problems they have.

Comment: Since Subversion is free, it may not be a bad idea to try it and see how it works and if there are problems, refine the list of requirements from whatever management system your situation requires.

Comment: Yeah,I used SVN before as a code repository and version control system. I loved it. Then the whole department switched to TFS. Personally I don't think TFS is any better than SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Percussion CMS is a GREAT **marketing** tool, someone recommended Document Management System for your applications you want to integrate and use with your CMS however; the key word is marketing tool. Percussion CMS is a great investment tool to help establish your online presence! With solutions like community marketing, personalization and web analytics these solutions are geared to generate a response from site users. Community marketing helps to engage socially with your visitors in facebook, twitter and community forums. Personalization helps with brand identity, features including product promotion and help your site's represent your company the way you want to be perceived. Lastly web analytics track users and report data back to marketers including information on bounce rates and geo-tracking. Reports showing whose visiting your site and their behaviors. Most importantly the Web CMS is fool proof. It is not code based or needs a webmaster to publish the content for your website. It's extremely user friendly.